# What is the meaning of "far to the east" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of "far to the east" in this text?

> It was only ofter a day and a night's delay that the emperor,  by detaching troops under Victor to make a long circuit, cross the canal **far to the east**, recall Lucilianus with the vanguard, and then attack the Surena's troops in the rear, was able to overcome the resistance in his front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google books, this passage is from a work on ancient history by George Rawlinson.

> It was only after a day and a night's delay that the emperor, by detaching troops under Victor to make a long circuit, cross the canal **far to the east**, recall Lucilianus with the vanguard, and then attack the surena's troops in the rear, was able to overcome the resistance in his front and carry his army across the cutting.

The emperor, by
detaching troops under Victor to
...   make a long circuit,
...   cross the canal **far to the east**,
...  recall Lucilianus with the vanguard,
...  and then attack the surena's troops in the rear
was able to overcome the resistance...

**"Far to the east"** applies to the canal mentioned. Troops were detached to travel to and cross a canal which was a long distance to the east of their original position.

*I'm editing my answer because of second thoughts. "Far to the east" may apply to "cross", rather than to canal. They may have been faced with a canal, and may have had to go east to cross it.*